# Display more than one item in array list

Tags: android, arrays, android-layout, listview, arraylist

Hello guys i would like to display more than one item horizontally in a single list. This items are picked from the dialog box that has two button ok and cancel. When you click okay it should pick the values from the edit text and a string value from the dialog and display in the list horizontally.

```
Array List Adapter
public class VehicleListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private Context context;
private List<String> vehicle_no;
public VehicleListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.vehicle_no = objects;


}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //get the vehicle number we are displaying
    String my_vehicle = vehicle_no.get(position);

    //get the inflater and inflate the XML layout for each item
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vehicle_num_layout, null);
    TextView txt_vehicle_num = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_vehicle_num);
    txt_vehicle_num.setText(my_vehicle);
    return view;
}
```

}

```
Activity with the list
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // get prompts.xml view
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);

            // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

            final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    // get user input and set it to result
                                    // edit text

                                    if(userInput.getText().toString().trim().length()==0) {
                                        userInput.setError("Vehicle Number Required");
                                        focus.start();
                                        String stime = focus.getText().toString();


                                    }
                                    else {
                                        result.setText(userInput.getText());
                                        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                                        vehicle_list.add(userInput.getText().toString().trim());
                                        VehicleListAdapter listAdapter = new VehicleListAdapter(StartWatch.this, 0, vehicle_list);
                                        list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: what error you are facing

Comment: add one more textView in 'vehicle_num_layout' file and use it in your adapter

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why you are creating new listview every time when user hit ok of dialog. Remove this line `ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);` from dialog positive button click.

Add line as shown below after your code in positive button click

```
VehicleListAdapter listAdapter = new VehicleListAdapter(StartWatch.this, 0, vehicle_list);
list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Add this line to tell adapter that data has been changed
```

Comment: Hi Divyang i want to have more than one item displayed in a row picked from dialog box. everytime okay button in the dialog is presssed a new list under the previous one in inserted

Comment: somebody with idea